# Vertex image training & recognition based on orientation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Does vertex AI recognize images if orientation is different?  Let's say I have a photo of something facing to the left.  If the image uploaded by the user is facing to the right, does that model training recognize it that way?

I have seen unexpected "unable to match" results, but maybe it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, this mainly depends on the training a model went through. [Models](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/explore-models#available-models) that are trained with large datasets having varying image orientations can definitely recognize them however others that are trained with limited datasets might be sensitive to orientations especially if the background is not clear and has significant degree of angle or rotation.

You can also train custom models to incorporate data augmentation techniques to enhance its robustness to orientation variations.

Here are some documents that you can review:

- [Train an image classification model](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/train-model)
- [Prepare image training data for classification](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/prepare-data)
- [Prepare image training data for object detection](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/object-detection/prepare-data)
- [Hello image data: Train an AutoML image classification model](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tutorials/image-classification-automl/training)